# phpmailer script, Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to send email from "dalalakhras20@gmail.com" to "dakhras@mcst.edu.sa" using phpmailer script.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //not ssl://smtp.gmail.com
$mail->Port = 465; 


$mail->SetFrom = "dalalakhras20@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("dakhras@mcst.edu.sa");

$mail->Subject = "aaa";
$mail->Body = "bbb";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
  echo "Message Sent!";
}
?>
```

in php.ini I set the following:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = ssl://smtp.gmail.com             
smtp_port = 465


; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = dalalakhras20@gmail.com
```

I did not change any thing in the class.phpmailer.php file.

I got this error:

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

I am using Apache2.2, any one can help me?

Comment: What happens when you try ports 25 or 587 instead of 465?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Charles. I changed the port number as you said in both php.ini file and in my code, and I restart the apathe server but unfortunately I still get the same error !!

Comment: Something is blocking outgoing mail connections.  You will need to speak to your web hosting provider.  Try PHPMailer's sendmail mode, perhaps?

Comment: emmm..okay. just I want to ask you about editing the php.ini file,do you think it is important? 
And do you think it is applicable to send the email to something like "dakhras@mcst.edu.sa"? I mean it is not something famous like yahoo, hotmail and gmail!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I made a lot of searches in the internet and I did not find solution to my issue using phpmailer. So, I have used php **pear** mail instead of it.

And you can find the steps in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH90nGNXab0

Thank you